# How to get Item from set based on parameter using Java8 features

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have a set with below items

```
Set<String> formatLookup = new HashSet<>();
formatLookup.add("DHMdhm");
formatLookup.add("THMthm");
formatLookup.add("JHMjhm");
```

and I am passing one String as below

```
String filterVal = "THM";
```

Now I want to check the filter value is present in which index of the set (the filter value order may vary like THM,HTM,MHT etc) and I want to return that item from set. Below is the code for this and it's working.

```
private static String getStoredFilter(String filterVal) {
    String format = "DHMdhm";
    boolean found = false;
    Set<String> formatLookup = new HashSet<>();
    formatLookup.add("DHMdhm");
    formatLookup.add("THMthm");
    formatLookup.add("JHMjhm");
    Iterator<String> setIterator = formatLookup.iterator();
    while (setIterator.hasNext()) {
        String fmt = setIterator.next();
        for (int j = 0; j < filterVal.length(); j++) {
            if (!(fmt).contains(String.valueOf(filterVal.charAt(j)))) {
                found = false;
                break;
            } else {
            found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            return fmt;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want to use Java8 features. I am new to Java8 and I tried with stream and `foreach`. But, since `foreach` can't return a value so I am not sure how to get this done.

Could you help me on this?

Comment: index of a `Set`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle permutations by simply bringing both, keys and input, into a canonical permutation, e.g. just sort them:

```
static String canonical(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(c);
    return String.valueOf(c);
}
```

Prepare a map from canonical key to specified string

```
// do this only once
private static final Map<String,String> formatLookup
    = Stream.of("DHMdhm", "THMthm", "JHMjhm")
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> canonical(s), Function.identity()));
```

and the actual operation

```
private static String getStoredFilter(String filterVal) {
    String key = canonical(filterVal);

    // check whether there's an exact match
    String quickChecked = formatLookup.get(key);
    if(quickChecked!=null) return quickChecked;

    // search for substring matches
    return formatLookup.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(key))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

If the strings may contain duplicate characters and you want to handle that, you only have to change the `canonical` method, e.g.

```
static String canonical(String s) {
    return s.codePoints().collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or).stream()
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Holger it is working as expected. But I wonder if it causes performance issue or not than the code as I mentioned.

Comment: This will always be faster than probing all possible permutations, especially for longer strings, as the number of possible permutations will explode.

Comment: It is accepting duplicate character also like THHHM, it should not accept it.

Comment: That's why I provided two variants of `canonical`, so you can use whatever matches your policy regarding duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done:

```
Set<String> formatLookup = new HashSet<>();
formatLookup.add("DHMdhm");
formatLookup.add("THMthm");
formatLookup.add("JHMjhm");
String filterVal = "THM";

String string = formatLookup.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.contains(filterVal))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse("noElement");
System.out.println(string);
```

Your output will be: `THMthm`

If you want the index of the initail set, please use the following code:

```
Set<String> formatLookup = new HashSet<>();
formatLookup.add("DHMdhm");
formatLookup.add("THMthm");
formatLookup.add("JHMjhm");
String filterVal = "THM";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(formatLookup);

String string = formatLookup.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.contains(filterVal))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse("noElement");
System.out.println(list.indexOf(string));
```

Your output will be: `1`

If you want to use all combinations of your `filterVal` String then use the following method:

```
private static void permutation(String prefix, String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1, n));
    }
}
```

The output of calling this method like this: `permutation("", filterVal);` is:

```
THM
TMH
HTM
HMT
MTH
MHT
```

Comment: you might want to use `findAny` instead and don't call `get` directly. what would happen if no such value is present?

Comment: Thanks @Alex. But one question if the order of the filter value vary like THM, HTM, MHT etc. how can it can be done?

Comment: You're welcome! Does not matter since we are using `findFirst()`. It finds the first occurrence from your Set. With the updated answer, if there is no occurrence, no Exception will be thrown.

Comment: @Eugene Just updated my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Alex Is it possible to get the value if the order of filterValue change? I want if all the character of the filter value present in any item of the set then return that item.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can use a method that creates permutation of the `filterVal` String. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: In this case I can use my code as I mentioned, but I want to use java 8 features stream, foreach etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of the Stream API you can use the `filter` method to get rid of values that you don't want, then use the `findAny()` method to get an item that matches the filter predicate.

If no items match the `filter` predicate `findAny()` will return an empty *Optional*.

```
private static String getStoredFilter(String filterVal) {
    Set<String> formatLookup = new HashSet<>();
    formatLookup.add( "DHMdhm");
    formatLookup.add( "THMthm");
    formatLookup.add( "JHMjhm");

    Optional<String> matchedVal = formatLookup.stream()
            .filter(val -> val.contains(filterVal))
            // At this point only matched values will be available
            .findAny(); // Get the first one that matches

    // Return the matched value if there is any, otherwise returns null
    return matchedVal.orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get matching first elem

```
    String e = formatLookup.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith(filterVal)).findFirst().get();
```

to collect all matching

```
    List<String> elems = formatLookup.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith(filterVal)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

getting position of first matching elem with Java9 (instead `Set` use `List` for index based )

```
    long index = formatLookup.stream().dropWhile(s -> s.startsWith(filterVal)).count();
```

Comment: @Sarvana this is returng DHMdhm not THMthm?